# How to fix .hover effect sticking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I put a .hover on an element it, and move the cursor away from the element, the hover effect will stay activated.

I solved this by using a "mouseover" and "mouseleave." But then when you make it so that if you click on the element and it changes some css, it will then change when the mouse leaves it because of this previous command.

I'm wondering what's the best way to solve this problem. I could use multiple "class remove" commands but if anyway knows how to fix the hover effect sticking that would be much less hassle!

I solved this by using a "mouseover" and "mouseleave." But then when you make it so that if you click on the element and it changes some css, it will then change when the mouse leaves it because of this previous command.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$j=jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery('.mkb').click(function(){
  jQuery('.mkb p').css('opacity','1 !important');
  jQuery('.mkb img').css('filter','brightness(75%) !important');


  });



/* ALS JE OP MKB hovered */
jQuery('.mkb').hover(function(){
  jQuery('.mkb p').css('opacity','1');
  jQuery('.mkb img').css('filter','brightness(75%)');

  });


/* ALS JE OP ZORG hovered */
jQuery('.zorg').mouseover(function(){
  jQuery('.zorg p').css('opacity','1');
  jQuery('.zorg img').css('filter','brightness(75%)');

 });

jQuery('.zorg').mouseleave(function(){
  jQuery('.zorg p').css('opacity','0');
  jQuery('.zorg img').css('filter','brightness(100%)');

  });

/* ALS JE OP catering hovered */
jQuery('.catering').mouseover(function(){
  jQuery('.catering p').css('opacity','1');
  jQuery('.catering img').css('filter','brightness(75%)');

  });

jQuery('.catering').mouseleave(function(){
  jQuery('.catering p').css('opacity','0');
  jQuery('.catering img').css('filter','brightness(100%)');

  });

/* ALS JE OP horeca hovered */
jQuery('.horeca').mouseover(function(){
  jQuery('.horeca p').css('opacity','1');
  jQuery('.horeca img').css('filter','brightness(75%)');

  });

jQuery('.horeca').mouseleave(function(){
  jQuery('.horeca p').css('opacity','0');
  jQuery('.horeca img').css('filter','brightness(100%)');

  });
```

Comment: Could you create a fiddle please?

Comment: Please insert your [code](/help/mcve) to your question! Without code, it's hard to help you

Comment: What is `.hover`? If you use `:hover` selector in your CSS it will work without javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be reverting the CSS applied by `hover()`. [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) shows that the function takes 2 parameters

> .hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )

And their provided example

```
$( "td" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "hover" );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "hover" );
  }
);
```

So what you should be doing is something like:

```
jQuery('.mkb').hover(
  function(){
    jQuery('.mkb p').css('opacity','1');
    jQuery('.mkb img').css('filter','brightness(75%)');
  }, function(){
    jQuery('.mkb p').css('opacity','0');
    jQuery('.mkb img').css('filter','brightness(0%)');
  }
);
```